# A non-closed circle icon in macOS menu bar that I cannot remove

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

On the top menu bar I have a non-closed circle and every time I click on it I get the colourful (loading circle icon). I cannot remove this thing. What is that?
[image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask what you actually see when you click on it? And, does right-clicking on it show you anything different? Or holding down the **option** key while clicking on it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and warm welcome :) Every time I click on it I see the rainbow ('loading') circle. And nothing changes if I right-click on it or use an option key.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to remove it, you could check your Login items:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups
2. Make sure your User Account is selected at top left
3. Click on the Login Items tab
4. Look for any items listed in the list of login items
5. Now remove any items you don't want to start automatically by clicking on its name (so it's highlighted) and then clicking on the minus <kbd>-</kbd> button
6. Once it's removed, exit System Preferences
7. Restart your Mac to test to see if the icon is still there